# how to use if statement for iterating through mutable datatypes to remove dividing by zero

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, exception

I am analyzing 2016 survey data taken by FreeCodeCamp. https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/2016-new-coder-survey

in particular, 2016-new-coder-survey/clean-data/2016-FCC-New-Coders-Survey-Data.csv

I am normalizing a plot by dividing the net recommendation amount (a difference) by the total (#sum of recommendations) for each x-value (Age).

for a few ages, there is zero recommendations, thus I end up dividing by zero and receiving ZeroDivisionError. I've already found a way to do it. but for the sake of learning, how could i accomplish fixing this with an if statement? could you explain what is wrong with the following code?

here is just all my variables, included for completeness.

```
data_file = pd.read_csv('FCC_New_Coders_Survey_Data.csv', dtype={'AttendedBootcamp': float, 'CodeEventOther': object, 'JobRoleInterestOther': object})
AttendedBootcamp = data_file['AttendedBootcamp']
BootcampFullJob = data_file['BootcampFullJobAfter']
BootcampRecommend = data_file['BootcampRecommend']
Age = data_file['Age']
JobYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 1]
JobNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 0]
RecYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 1]
RecNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 0]
RecYesJobYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 1][data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 1 ]
RecNoJobYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 0][data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 1 ]
RecYesJobNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 1][data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 0 ]
RecNoJobNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 0][data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 0 ]
```

here lies my failed code

```
numerator = [len(RecYesJobYes[RecYesJobYes.Age == i]) - len(RecNoJobYes[RecNoJobYes.Age == i]) for i in range(16, 60)]
denomerator = [len(RecYesJobYes[RecYesJobYes.Age == i]) + len(RecNoJobYes[RecNoJobYes.Age == i]) for i in range(16, 60)]
```

here is my attempt at exception handling

```
try:
    bananasplit = [int(m) / int(b) for b,m in zip(denomerator, numerator)]
except ZeroDivisionError:
        b = 1 in denomerator
```

here is my if statement

```
for b in [int(m) / int(b) for b,m in zip(denomerator, numerator)][:]:
    if ZeroDivisionError:
        b = 1 in denomerator
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue lies with `b`, is that right?

Comment: In your last code snippet, you are evaluating `ZeroDivisionError` as an expression, then testing its truth value.  It will always be true.  It is equivalent to using `if True:`

Comment: @Tom Karzes but, if there is no division by 0 zero then my if=statement would never be called right?

Comment: @ COLSPEED  i want to represent the element in the list that creates the ZeroDivisionError, isnt that b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if/else in the list comprehension like so (technically we are using a ternary operator):

```
bananasplit = [int(m) / int(b) if int(b) != 0 else int(m) for b,m in zip(denomerator, numerator)]
```

If you want to use exception handling, you should use a loop rather than list comprehension:

```
bananasplit = []
for b, m in zip(denomerator, numerator):
    try:
        bananasplit.append(int(m)/int(b))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        bananasplit.append(int(m))
```